# Visual Studio not responding when using razor

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, blazor

When I open razor or markdown files, Visual Studio it does not respond anymore. It is reproduceable with the same setup on different machines.

The log shows following errormessage (the system is in german)

```
Programm devenv.exe, version 17.9.34622.214 kann nicht mehr unter Windows ausgführt werden und wurde beendet. Überprüfen Sie den Problemverlauf in der Systemsteuerung "Sicherheit und Wartung", um nach weiteren Details zum Problem zu suchen.
```

To the environment:
Windows Server 2016 with RDP access, Hyper-V.
Visual Studio (tested with 17.8.7 and 17.9.2)
Basic Blazor Wasm Client stand alone project

A partial fix is to change the font from the default to an other one. But it is still slower as on other machines. How do I fix the Problem completely?

Comment: This might be a bug to report: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022